# radio buttons inside datatemplate wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to access radio buttons inside datatemplate which is in a datagrid. I came across a lot of answers but none work for me.
I have 3 different radio buttions in 3 different columns. i just cant figure out how to access those radio buttons and its killing me, i'v been struggling with it for days PLEASE HELP.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Yes" Width="Auto">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Opacity="0.8">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="rbYes" GroupName="{Binding QuestionID}" Content="Yes" Grid.Column="0" />
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="No" Width="Auto">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Opacity="0.8">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="rbNo" GroupName="{Binding QuestionID}" Content="No" Grid.Column="0" />
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="N/A" Width="Auto">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Opacity="0.8">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="rbNA" GroupName="{Binding QuestionID}" Content="N/A" Grid.Column="0" />
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

And here is my code behind. I have changed it so many times.

```
RadioButton rbYes = (RadioButton)FindName("rbYes");
RadioButton rbNo = (RadioButton)FindName("rbNo");
RadioButton rbNA = (RadioButton)FindName("rbNA");

if (rbYes.IsChecked == true)
{
    rbNo.IsChecked = false;
    rbNA.IsChecked = false;
    int questionID = Convert.ToInt32(drv["QuestionID"]);
    questionAnswer = "Yes".ToString();
    if (drv["Notes"].ToString() == "")
    {
        string notes = null;
    }
    else
    {
        string notes = drv["Notes"].ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are familiar with data binding (as you have already bound the QuestionID) my suggestion is as follows;

1. Have 3 boolean properties say IsYes, IsNo, IsNA in the object through which the data is populated in the datagrid. Make the collection that is bound to the ItemSource of your datagrid as an ObservableCollection.
2. Bind the IsChecked of the radio buttons to these three properties respectively.

By doing the above steps, you don't have to worry about going deep into the cells of your datagrid to find the controls and to know whether they are set or not.

[UPDATE] Sorry for the delay. I was in a meeting. The Code is as follows.
Please note that this is a very rough mock up of how to achieve the concept which I mentioned above.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="testWPFApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:testWPFApplication"
        mc:Ignorable="d" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" SelectionMode="Single"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedQuestion,Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Question Id" Binding="{Binding QuestionId}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Question" Binding="{Binding QuestionDescription}" Width="3*" IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Yes">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <RadioButton GroupName="{Binding QuestionId}" IsChecked="{Binding IsYes, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" 
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="No">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <RadioButton GroupName="{Binding QuestionId}" IsChecked="{Binding IsNo, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" 
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="N/A">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <RadioButton GroupName="{Binding QuestionId}" IsChecked="{Binding IsNA, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" 
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

        <Button Grid.Row="1" Width="100" x:Name="btnCheckAnswers" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5" Click="btnCheckAnswers_Click" Content="Check Answers" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs** (code behind. can be moved a different ViewModel class)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace testWPFApplication
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Question> _questions;
        private Question _selectedQuestion;

        public ObservableCollection<Question> Questions
        {
            get { return _questions; }
            set
            {
                _questions = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Questions");
            }
        }

        public Question SelectedQuestion
        {
            get { return _selectedQuestion; }
            set
            {
                _selectedQuestion = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedQuestion");
                OnSelectedQuestionChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string strPropertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(strPropertyName));
            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            Init();

        }

        private void Init()
        {
            CreateMockData();
        }

        private void CreateMockData()
        {
            if (Questions == null)
            {
                Questions = new ObservableCollection<Question>();
            }
            else
            {
                Questions.Clear();
            }

            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                Question q = new Question
                {
                    QuestionId = i,
                    QuestionDescription = "Sample Question " + i.ToString(),
                    IsYes = false,
                    IsNA = false,
                    IsNo = false
                };
                Questions.Add(q);
            }
        }

        private void OnSelectedQuestionChanged()
        {
            if(SelectedQuestion != null)
            {

            }
        }

        private void btnCheckAnswers_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StringBuilder strQuestionAnswer = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (Question item in Questions)
            {
                strQuestionAnswer.AppendLine(item.QuestionDescription + ":");
                strQuestionAnswer.AppendLine("IsYes:" + item.IsYes);
                strQuestionAnswer.AppendLine("IsNo:" + item.IsNo);
                strQuestionAnswer.AppendLine("IsNA:" + item.IsNA);
            }

            MessageBox.Show(strQuestionAnswer.ToString());
        }
    }

    public class Question
    {
        public int QuestionId { get; set; }

        public string QuestionDescription { get; set; }

        public bool IsYes { get; set; }

        public bool IsNo { get; set; }

        public bool IsNA { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Window Load**

[image: Window_load]

**Few values set**

[image: Few_values_set]

**Result when the button is clicked**

[image: result_when_the_button_is_clicked]

Hope this example helps you to address the issue that you have.

Comment: Im not an expert programmer but i do understand what you saying...im going to do that now and i will just let you know if i experience any problems.

Comment: Thank you so much, this answer is amazing...I didn't do it like you did it...again, thank you...you really good.. :)

Comment: Hey...I need help again...i have a button next to my radio buttons...each time i click the button it should clear all the radio buttons for that row. but i dont know how to do this...do you know of anyway this can be done...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answering so quickly. But thats not the problem, the problem is, I'm try to access the radiobuttons im using but i can find the buttons with the FindName function. Null is returned for rbYes, rbNo and rbNA. I don't know if my explanation is good enough.